# How to listen for event of closed stdin in a tornado loop?

Tags: python, tornado

This is a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717077/handling-stdin-with-tornado) on handling the data in the socket. However, I am unable to capture the "stdin closed" event. Here's what I have now:

```
import sys
import tornado

from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import Application, RequestHandler

class MainHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.finish("foo")
application = Application([ (r"/", MainHandler), ])

@tornado.gen.coroutine
def close_callback(*args, **kwargs):
    print args, kwargs

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)

    stdin = tornado.iostream.PipeIOStream(sys.stdin.fileno())
    stdin.set_close_callback(close_callback)

    IOLoop.instance().start()
```

And a test:

```
$ ./tornado_sockets.py   # expect to close stdin
<C-d>    # nothing happens
```

Another test:

```
$ echo expect_stdin_to_be_closed | ./tornado_sockets.py
# nothing happens
```

How can I listen for closing of stdin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote [sys.stdin does not close on ctrl-d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666923/sys-stdin-does-not-close-on-ctrl-d):

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> has a strange effect. It doesn't close the input stream, but only causes a C-level fread() to return an empty result.

So basically you need to assert read line with empty string. Some example without `PipeIOStream`:

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
import sys

def on_stdin(fd, events):
    line = fd.readline()
    print("received: %s" % repr(line))
    if line == '':
        print('stdin ctr+d')
        sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    IOLoop.instance().add_handler(sys.stdin, on_stdin, IOLoop.READ)
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```

With `PipeIOStream` it is pretty straightforward using `read_until_close`. Callback will be called on close or on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

```
import sys
import tornado
import tornado.iostream
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from functools import partial

def read(stdin, data):
    print(data)
    # below lines are unnecessary they are only for testing purposes
    stdin.close()
    IOLoop.instance().stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    stdin = tornado.iostream.PipeIOStream(sys.stdin.fileno())
    stdin.read_until_close(callback=partial(read, stdin))
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```